# How to insert into oracle database with custom object type using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Given the following code:

Custom oracle object type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE address_type AS OBJECT ( 
   street          VARCHAR2(30),
   city            VARCHAR2(20),
   state           CHAR(2),
   postal_code     VARCHAR2(6) )
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, CHAR, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import UserDefinedType


class AddressType(UserDefinedType):
    def get_col_spec(self):
        return "ADDRESS_TYPE"

    def bind_processor(self, dialect):
        def process(value):
            if value is not None:
                street = value['street']
                city = value['city']
                state = value['state']
                postal_code = value['postal_code']
                return f"ADDRESS_TYPE('{street}', '{city}', '{state}', '{postal_code}')"
            return None
        return process

    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        def process(value):
            if value is not None:
                return {'street': value.street, 'city': value.city, 'state': value.state, 'postal_code': value.postal_code}
            return None
        return process

Base = declarative_base()

class MyEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'MY_TABLE'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    custom_address = Column(AddressType, nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('oracle://your_username:your_password@your_host:your_port/your_database')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

... somewhere later ...

new_entity = MyEntity(id=1, custom_address={'street':'street', 'city':'city', 'state':'ST', 'postal_code':'000000'}

db_session.add(new_entity)
db_session.commit(). # This will throw the error
```

I can successfully read from the database using sqlalchemy.  But when trying to create a record I get several errors. Even when returning None, I get the error:

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected address_type got CHAR`

How can I insert a new entity using sqlalchemy?

EDIT:

Thanks to the tip in the comments: If I use the method `bind_expression` instead, I can actually write a hardcoded value to the database.

```
 def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return text(f"ADDRESS_TYPE('street', 'random city', 'NY', '10001')")
```

But I am not able to access any data I set on the variable `custom_address`. The `bindvalue` does not contain any of those. How do I access my data inside the `bind_expression` function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58668255/1509264 might give you some pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is indeed helpful, but still not working. I cannot figure out, how to get access my data inside the `bind_expression` function.